# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol while validating xml string with xsd schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate xml with xsd schema, but at the time of validation it throws,

java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

What I have done so far is,

```
        public boolean ValidateXML(String  xmlContent) throws  Exception {
        try
        {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("ABC/XYX/PQR.xsd"));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlContent));
}...
```

What is going wrong, validator.validate this step it is throwing an exception, do I need to provide encoded string here?

If I do it with file I mean xmlContent from a file,

```
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(filePath)));
```

then it's working fine.
I do not want xml content from a file but from string object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert your string into a StreamResource:

```
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
```

Comment: Yes it worked, Thanks. it need to be encoded, isn't String takes care of it.

Comment: The problem was not the encoding, but the wrong type in the StreamResource constructor. If you call StreamResource constructor with a String argument it tries to parse this string as an URL. See it in the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource(java.lang.String)

My suggestion calls the StreamResource constructor with an InputStream argument, and to do that I wrapped the xmlContent string with an InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by Balázs Nemes. For older versions of Java you may not have the `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` available. We have a Java 1.6 app and use a compatible Apache Commons library, so this worked having `String xml`:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.CharEncoding;
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(org.apache.commons.codec.CharEncoding.UTF_8))));
```